# android - sending POST with json to django server

Tags: android, django, http, server

I have a android app which tries to register a user to django server, sending a POST request with json.

the response code I get is 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

**Android code:**

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
registerUserRequest = new HttpPost("http://10.100.102.9:8000/users/register");

public void registerUser(){


    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userMap.put("username", "UserName");
    userMap.put("password", "12345");
    userMap.put("first_name", "first");
    userMap.put("last_name", "last");

    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(params);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
    registerUserRequest.setEntity(se);
    registerUserRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    new executeRequest().execute(registerUserRequest);
}

 private class executeRequest extends AsyncTask<HttpRequest, Void, Integer>
 {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(HttpRequest... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpRequest request = params[0];
        int responseCode = -1;
        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(registerUserRequest,
                    responseHandler);

            Log.d("Response of REGISTER_USER request", response.toString());
            responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // This exception raised
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseCode;
    }

}
```

**The exception raised is ClientProtocolException in the AsyncTask.**

**Django Code:**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def register(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username = serializer.init_data['username'],
                password = serializer.init_data['password'],
                first_name = serializer.init_data['first_name'],
                last_name = serializer.init_data['last_name'],
            )

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**The URL is fine I tested it** - "http://10.100.102.9:8000/users/register"

ERROR: the response code I get is 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

```
05-24 13:05:14.317: W/System.err(15625): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
05-24 13:05:14.317: W/System.err(15625):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
05-24 13:05:14.327: W/System.err(15625):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
05-24 13:05:14.337: W/System.err(15625):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
05-24 13:05:14.337: W/System.err(15625):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

thanks!

Comment: Please post the error too.

Comment: you mean in client-side? edited my question

Comment: I mean the error that Django in your server returns to your client.

Comment: i tried to look for how to debug in PyCharm Django projects, couldn't really find any help. the message in the Console is [24/May/2015 17:11:10]"POST /users/register HTTP/1.1" 500 66235 I realize its not much... do you happen to know how to debug in django?

Comment: Since you cannot access the server report but you are using PyCharm, it has a very good debugger. Just create a breakpoint early in your view and step to the problem.

Comment: okay i did put breakpoints.. When I post the url from the browser its going into the register method just fine. when I post from android mobile phone (code in the question) its not event going into the method and I get 500. I dont know where can I see the errors in pycharm.. ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to view the response from within android? Another possibility is to change default logging and let Django email you any 500 error. How do you take care of csrf (although I would have expected 403 not 500)?

Comment: what is scrf..? worth to point out that when I access the url from the mobile phone's browser it work fine. from the app I get 500 so it must be the code..

Comment: solved it! I did look at the response in the client side. apparently I needed to add a / in the end of the URL.. stupied..

Answer (score 3):

500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR means error in server side code not mobile side.
check the exception happened in server side.